# HTML isn't changed when removing data item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make the `data-title` value empty strings for the second `option` (where `value="24"`). Although the `console.log` statements say the `data-title` is now empty, when I inspect the element on my browser, the text is still there. Is there a way to dynamically change the HTML on the browser?

**HTML:**

```
<select name="ctl00$phBody$ddlTimeScale" id="ctl00_phBody_ddlTimeScale" class="timeline_options" data-list-items-tooltip-enabled="true">
    <option value="1">1 Hour</option>
    <option value="24" data-title="text 24">1 Day</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="144" data-title="text 144">1 Week</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery/JavaScript:**

```
var selectID = "ctl00_phBody_ddlTimeScale";

console.log("Before 24: " + $('#' + selectID + ' option[value="24"]').data('title'));

$('#' + selectID + ' option[value="24"]').data('title', '');

console.log("After 24: " + $('#' + selectID + ' option[value="24"]').data('title'));
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sp03musf/)

Comment: Why do you care what you see in the source if the console is reporting that the value is empty?

Comment: $("#yourid").attr("data-title","newval")

Comment: I believe this is just an issue with the inspector, if the value of the actual node is reporting to be empty.

Comment: It's not an issue with the node, and neither is it a trivial issue. It is because the `.data()` attribute can only be used to **read** HTML5 data attributes and to access the jQuery data object. If you want to modify the DOM value, you have to stick to `.attr()`

Comment: I don't understand the downvote, but that's fine. An explanation would be nice though

Comment: @j08691 There is code that adjusts the UI based on what this JavaScript/HTML produce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSFIDDLE DEMO -> http://jsfiddle.net/sp03musf/1/

[.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) stores data on the matched elements which is different from the attributes `data-attr` and [.removeData](https://api.jquery.com/removeData/) removes the data attribute from the storage.

So, basically when you want to remove the attribute, the `.data('title')` will still be intact since it comes from the client side storage. Use `.removeData()` to remove that too.

```
var selectId = $('#' + selectID + ' option[value="24"]');
selectId.attr('data-title', ''); // empty it in the DOM
selectId.removeData('title'); // clear storage
```

Note:

If you don't intend to use localStorage, don't write `data('title')` at all. Just use `.attr(data-title)` every single time, so you don't have to `removeData()`.

```
console.log("Before 24: " + $('#' + selectID + ' option[value="24"]').attr('data-title'));
$('#' + selectID + ' option[value="24"]').attr('data-title', '1');
console.log("After 24: " + $('#' + selectID + ' option[value="24"]').attr('data-title'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Other than that, you can use .attr() to set the data-title into empty value.

```
$('#' + selectID + ' option[value="24"]').attr('data-title', '');
```

Comment: That is correct :) `.data()` is only used to access the HTML5 data attribute, and to store the value in a jQuery object. In order to **write** to the attribute, the conventional `.attr()` will have to be used.